# Stationarity test using R

Tags: r, statistics, statistical-test

Using the stationarity test I am try to extract the result corresponding to the "p-value for T" line which in this case is 0, but I cannot seem to do it using R.

```
    > stationarity(lg.day.ret)
1
2
3
4
5
6
N = 2609, nblock = 11, n_block_max = 238, dt =     1.0000
7
8
9
10
11
12
13
14
15
16
17
18
Priestley-Subba Rao stationarity Test for lg.day.ret
----------------------------------------------------
Samples used              : 2609 
Samples available         : 2607 
Sampling interval         : 1 
SDF estimator             : Multitaper 
  Number of (sine) tapers : 5 
  Centered                : TRUE 
  Recentered              : FALSE 
Number of blocks          : 11 
Block size                : 237 
Number of blocks          : 11 
p-value for T             : 0 
p-value for I+R           : 0.08981712 
p-value for T+I+R         : 0
```

where lg.day.ret can just be any real vector.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking a guess at what you're looking for...

```
library(fractal) # Don't forget to include where the function comes from
# in your example

results <- stationarity(ecgrr, n.block=8) #using sample data from
# fractal package

str(results) # Tells you more about the object
pvalues <- attr(results,"pvals")

##           T          I+R        T+I+R 
## 0.0001217759 0.0592977070 0.0013647583 

pvalues[1]
##           T 
## 0.0001217759
```